# php striping with exceptions or reorganizing htmlspecialchar

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

I'm trying to build a web site basicly for sharing sample codes and comments. My problem is avoiding any tags/scripts except a img and some very common ones like i b... I tried different solutions but at one point all of them stacks: If user uses < not for tags, meaning less than...

First started my code with spliting the   tags, split_tag the other places and htmlspecialchars to the code part then remerge them. But still if user uses < anywhere in text part it erases the post until it sees a >. (Also tried to avoid strip_tags to erase, by putting a whitespace after < but couldnt find a way to recognize if it is a tag or less than)

Then i tried it backward. Used htmlspecialchars for all post and change the specific ones back to tag appearance. This time i got trouble with all replace functions because some of them didnt worked correctly or overlap with eachother. I feel like there is a simple solution but i couldnt looked at the right angle. Any suggestions ?

`$yazi = htmlspecialchars($_POST["yazi"]);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;a href=&quot;', '<a href"', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;&#47a&gt;', '</a>', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;code&gt;','<code>', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;&#47codea&gt;', '</code>', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;br&gt;', '<br>', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;i&gt;', '<i>', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;&#47i&gt;', '</i>', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;b&gt;','<b>',$yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;&#47b&gt;','</b>',$yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;p&gt;','<p>',$yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;&#47p&gt;','</p>',$yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&lt;img src=&quot;', '<img src="', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&quot;/&gt;', '"/>', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&quot; /&gt;', '" />', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&quot;&gt;', '">', $yazi);

$yazi = str_replace('&quot; &gt;', '" >', $yazi);`

Comment: Have you thought about escaping ALL HTML, then allowing users to add formatting and images using a different markup language like markdown or bbcode? That way the code samples can be treated separately from comments. I'm basically thinking of the way SO works.

Comment: In that case please use markdown. BBCode is horrible once you got used to the simplicity of markdown. And by the way, at least the markdown here on SO allows some HTML

Comment: Thanks for answers. I insisted on my onw way and solved it: I used a explode several times to find out exceptional tags and replace them with <img , <a , /a> ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an HTML sanitizer.

http://htmlpurifier.org/ looks pretty good.